# installation of fedora : nothing happens

Tags: installation, virtualbox, fedora, live-cd

I'm trying to install fedora 33 on VirtualBox (Windows host) using an iso file.

The settings used are as shown on the following image:
[image: Settings]

When I start running the live iso image, I get the installation menu
[image: Live CD menu]

I choose "Fedora-MATE_compiz" and then I get a black screen that stays forever, when I'm supposed to get the Live Feodra  desktop. I also noticed that there is no green dot blinking on the CD symbol on the bottom bar.

[image: Black screen]

Comment: And the logs can be found here : [logs](https://pastebin.com/uxcYa626)

Comment: If you try the `VBoxSVGA` graphics controller rather than your current `VMSVGA` setting, does that help?

Comment: No, still the same with the underline cursor blinking forever.

Comment: Does the ISO pass `Test this media & start Fedora-MATE_compiz-Live 33`?

Comment: If I select the test in the menu, it does nothing as well.

Comment: I installed Fedora on a another virtualbox host (and it is working properly) and I copied the VDI image on my laptop. And still nothing.
And the symbol for HDD isn't doing anything. there is usually a green dot blinking, showing that it does something but here, nothing.

Comment: Curious.  I use a Linux host for VirtualBox so I'm not sure what is different with a Windows host.  Perhaps asking your question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) will have other users more familiar with the Windows VirtualBox host.